# Trouble with rolling hash implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was trying to solve a question where i have to find the number of palindromes of length "plen" in a string.(at most length 30000). I thought of using a rolling hash technique to calculate hashes of all substrings of length plen and their reverse. If the hashes match, i assume equality , hoping that my choice of constants should be sufficient. The following is my implementation, I seem to have messed up. It does not work for simple cases too. Could someone tell me my mistake? Thanks.

```
int MUL = 37;
int MOD = 9999991;

for(int i = 1 , pwr = 1 ; i < plen ; i++) pwr = (pwr * MUL) % MOD;
long long hash = number[0];
long long revHash = number[plen - 1];
for(int i = 1 ; i < plen  ; i++)
{
    hash = (MUL*hash + number[i])%MOD;
    revHash = (revHash*MUL + number[plen - i - 1])%MOD;

}

cout << hash << " " << revHash <<"\n";

int cnt = (hash == revHash);

for(int i = plen ; i < numbers ; i++)
{
    hash = (hash + (MOD - pwr)*number[i - plen])%MOD;
    hash = (hash*MUL + number[i])%MOD;


    revHash = ((revHash + MOD - number[i - plen]))%MOD;
    revHash = (revHash + pwr*number[i])%MOD;

    cnt += (hash == revHash);

    cout << hash << " " << revHash << "\n";

}
```

Comment: As a rule, equal hashes do not imply equal values, so *(regardless of whether you made a mistake in your implementation)* the idea will not work.  Off the top of my head, you could do this in `O(n^2)` using dynamic programming by noticing that the string starting at position `i1` and ending at position `i2` is a palindrome iff the start and end letters are equal, and the string starting at position `i1+1` and ending at position `i2-1` is also a palindrome.

Comment: Oh, I misread, I thought you were looking for the number of palindromes of any length.  The number of palindromes of length `p` in a string of length `n` is even easier:  There are only `n-p+1` possible strings, so just check them all individually.